# Need Clarifications in iPhone Sensors

Tags: ios, iphone, sensors, motion, cmmotionmanager

Is it possible to get the details like:

1. The name and model number of the sensor
2. The maximum range of the sensor in the sensor's unit.
3. Power consumption of the sensor.
4. The name of the vendor that provides the sensor.

Will Apple provide this all information through coding? Please guide me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide such information in any form, what is known comes from 3rd parties that disassemble and analyze the devices.

Check sites such as [Chipworks](http://www.chipworks.com), [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown) and [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com).

Also offshore publications that speculate on what vendors are supplying Apple.